STEREO-A/B conjunction
STEREO satellites are on somewhat different solar orbits, so their separation angle changes over time. On 2011-02-06, they were in “opposition” (180-degree separation).1 On 2023-08-12, close approach of STEREO-A to Earth was reported.1 It may accidentally somewhat coincide with STEREO-A/B “conjunction” (0-degree separation), which may have occurred around 2023-07-25.2 But I am unable to find a report on this event, I guess it has to do with the decade long contact loss of STEREO-B, so that it's no longer relevant.
Is the “Where is STEREO?”2 tool reliable? Are there existing reports of the “conjunction” event? Can it be independently verified by some other means?

According to Horizons, the STEREO-A close approach was ~2023-Aug-17 11:00 UT https://i.sstatic.net/7oVh9fLe.png Horizons also has reconstructed trajectory data for STEREO-B https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=-235

It looks like they had the same heliocentric ecliptic longitude ~2023-Jul-25 16:00 UTC https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=YES&COMMAND=-234&CENTER=%4010&START_TIME=%272023-Jul-25+UT%27&STOP_TIME=2023-Jul-26&STEP_SIZE=1h&QUANTITIES=31&OBJ_DATA=NO https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=YES&COMMAND=-235&CENTER=%4010&START_TIME=%272023-Jul-25+UT%27&STOP_TIME=2023-Jul-26&STEP_SIZE=1h&QUANTITIES=31&OBJ_DATA=NO

I expect that Where is STEREO? uses SPICE, like Horizons does. I'd be very surprised if there was better STEREO-B trajectory data than what JPL has. So it's rather unlikely that there's any way to verify it independently.

Partial answer:
I did a quick run for Stereo-B in Horizons and looked at the output.
*******************************************************************************
 Revised:  Feb 08, 2023             STEREO-B Spacecraft                    -235
                                http://stereo.gsfc.nasa.gov/
 NOTE: 
  Contact with STEREO-B was lost 2014-Oct-01. 

  After 22 months, contact was regained at 22:27 UTC on August 21, 2016, when 
  the Deep Space Network established a lock on STEREO-B for 2.4 hours. The
  trajectory here is updated to use that tracking data. 

  It has been determined the spacecraft is in an uncontrolled spin of 
  3 deg/second. 

  2023-Feb-08:
   There has been no contact or new tracking data since 2016, but an updated
   prediction was added to support a search effort.

  2017-Sep-20: 
   Fix did NOT occur. Last contact with the spacecraft was September 23, 2016.

  2016-Oct-14: 
   Another opportunity to potentially fix the spacecraft will not occur until 
   mid-2017. Once its computer is powered on there will be about two minutes 
   to upload the fix before STEREO-B enters failure mode again. 

  http://stereo-ssc.nascom.nasa.gov/behind_status.shtml

The 2.4 hour "lock" on August 21, 2016 seems long enough to get good range-rate tracking data from its coherent transponders, assuming that

The STEREO spacecraft HAVE coherent transponders (or some other mechanism for range-rate measurements) and
That's what a "lock" means.

For 1. I've just asked

Did the STEREO spacecraft have coherent transponders for range-rate measurements for tracking and orbit predictions? If not, how was it tracked>

I don't see any information there about what non gravitational parameters (e.g. Marsden parameters as shown from Horizons here) are included in the orbit propagation (e.g. solar photon pressure) - it's hard to judge the long term prediction accuracy of Horizons for Stereo-B.
Right now I guess we'd have to say "pretty good" because JPL is definitely "pretty good" at this sort of thing.
That said:
I'll keep poking around to see if a more quantitative answer is possible. Stay tuned!
